# How to generate correct access token when my app already has Page Public Content Access

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Our team is creating an app that analyzes Facebook reviews/recommendations.  We have submitted an initial version of the app to FB for approval to use Page Public Content Access (PPCA), and have been approved.  However when we started testing it after approval and after going to Live mode, we have not been able to generate any tokens that enable us to access the public content we are looking for.
There was a similar question posted recently, 54943575/facebook-graph-api-review-rating-data-with-page-public-content-access.  However the answers that appeared for that one said that you can't access this content without manage_pages permission for each individual page, while the FB documentation clearly says you can do so with the Page Public Content Access: "Allows read-only access to public data on Pages for which you lack the manage_page login permission. Readable data includes business metadata, public comments, posts, and reviews."  It is true that you need manage_pages in order to write, e.g. delete or post, content to any pages.  The documentation also says that with PPCA permission, an allowed use is "Provide aggregated, anonymized public content for competitive analysis and benchmarking", for which clearly you would not be able to get manage_pages permission for all pages you access. 
What this question boils down to is this" is the FB documentation for PPCA correct, and if so, how can we generate the access token(s) needed to use it, now that we have it?

Update: the following graph call (from the FB Graph API SDK for Python) that retrieves "posts" does work:

page_posts = graph.get_connections(id=getpage_id, connection_name='posts')

While the following one that attempts to retrieve reviews/ratings, does not:

page_reviews = graph.get_connections(id=getpage_id, connection_name='ratings')

The latter call produces the error: 
(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException",

The Facebook Developers documentation says that the Page Public Content Access applies to ratings as well as posts, but this appears to contradict that, unless we are calling the graph incorrectly here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get a Page Token of Pages you manage - for other Pages (and Page Public Content Access), you can just use an App Access Token. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

**For ratings/reviews, you MUST use a Page Token.** Page Public Content Access only gives you access to the Page feed and photos, for example.

Comment: Thanks luschn -- we thought that was the most likely answer, but have not gotten it to work yet.  Currently our app does not have "Login with Facebook" and we are thinking we have to add that, or convert it to a Desktop App, in order to get this permission working with our app token.

Comment: We have implemented Login With Facebook, and as mentioned above already have passed app review with approval to use Page Public Content Access.  However it is not working.  We've found no Facebook documentation showing how to use this access, and no relevant Q&A on Stackoverflow.   Are there any examples, sample code or secret handshakes that anyone is aware of that could help here?

Comment: what means "not working"? any specific errors now? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Correction: the access does not work for the "ratings" field -- reviews of the page though FB documentation says it should.  name, id and posts fields work.

Comment: Answering luschn: we are just trying to access public ratings (reviews) and posts for certain selected pages.  Then we do summaries and statistics on the text of the ratings and posts. The specific error when we try to access the ratings field is  "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210,
    "fbtrace_id": "D+4E31XqYDI"

Comment: of course you cannot access the ratings with an app token, for that you do need a page token. but you are right, the api reference does not tell you that. did i miss that information in your question? because that would have been very easy to answer, sorry :) - i will update my answer

Comment: When we originally asked the question, we thought that there was some other access token needed in order to use the page public content access.  Now we understand that it's just the app token that's needed, but the page public content access does not appear to include reviews, in direct contradiction to the documentation.   Thanks luschn for your helpful answers.